# Re-stream live video feed

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming

I currently have a device running Ubuntu with an Asus Xtion Pro Live attached. What I'm trying to do is to capture the video and *push* it to a server, and then have the server re-stream it so that other clients that connect to my server can view the stream. The server is running Windows and has a public ip.

What I currently have now is, while the device is on the same network as a client, the client can connect directly to the device to view the stream. For example, if the device has an ip of `192.168.1.101`, I can set the device to have the video stream at `192.168.1.101:8181/stream?topic=/camera/rgb/image_color`, and the client can simply type the above url into a browser to view the stream. What I'm trying to overcome is, if I wanted to use my device elsewhere and use a 3G/4G dongle, or a different wifi network, I wouldn't be able to connect to it directly. So I want it to *push* the stream to my server, and then have clients connect to the server to view the stream through a webapp. The server currently runs a webapp on Tomcat, using Java, JavaScript, JSP, jQuery, MSSQL. I want to add on functionality to the webapp to allow viewing of the video stream from the Asus Xtion.

I roughly know that there will be three things I have to do:

1. Stream the Asus Xtion camera feed to the server,
2. Receive the stream on my server somehow, and
3. Have my server re-stream the video.

But I don't really have any idea on how to go about doing this. I know that with VLC, I can *pull* a video stream, and then re-stream it. However this won't work for me because I won't be able to pull from the device; it doesn't have a public ip so it wouldn't be accessible.

I can't find anything that applies to my situation, but I'm guessing that this is possible. For example, with YouTube live, any account with the feature enabled can stream their webcam feed to YouTube, then viewers who want the view the stream can just do so via YouTube. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hey, Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if the stream server doesnt have a public IP, still you can make it accessible to outside network, by setting up port-forwarding in the NAT router. Wont this solve your issue ?

Comment: How would I do this with cellular data using 3G/4G? Also, if say I were to use a public free wifi hotspot, I wouldn't have access to do port-forwarding in their router.

Comment: i see you are moving on different networks to do the broadcast, right ? In that case, set up a streaming server somewhere with a public IP, give yours viewers the streaming link from that server, and whereever you go, capture and push to that streaming server. That way your viewers will always be able to see the stream.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said in my question.