# How To Re-Stream Web Camera Via Server

Tags: video, video-streaming, mjpeg

I am designing a solution which will allow video from a webcam attached to a Raspberry Pi to be streamed to my server in AWS and then re-streamed to a browser accessing a website on the AWS Server. Many Pis would be involved and a user would trigger and access the feed coming from their own Pi on demand.

This is unfamiliar territory for me so I dont really know where to start and I am seeking advice on the best architecture.

So far I am considering a process (ideally python) on each Pi which would open a web socket connection to the server. The server would track each socket in terms of the user account it related to. A user would then connect to the server, trigger a signal over the web socket to turn on their own Pi video feed, and the video feed would be sent to my server. They idea is they should then see the video feed via a URL on my site NOT via a URL on the Pi - this would resolve any NAT access issues.

How can I send the video feed from each Pi webcam to the server, such that it appears the live feed is coming from the server itself?

It is essentially the same thing requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299255/re-stream-live-video-feed) which did not receive an answer.

Comment: "This is unfamiliar territory for me" and "don't waste my time by suggesting..." really shouldn't go in the same post.  It's awfully arrogant to be worried about *your* time when you're asking the time of others with your question.

Comment: Point taken. Sorry for my 'baggage'. But its related to a prior question I posted where I pointed out that port forwarding was not a suitable solution and I was then asked multiple questions as to why. When I saw the similar question to mine (which I provided as a link) with port forwarding suggested as a solution which didnt match the problem it reminded me of that incident and I was simply trying to avoid unnecessary dialog on this post that had already been covered on the linked post and (in my mind) on another one. I didnt actually mean to be rude.

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes the easiest and most powerful tool is **UV4L** as mentioned in the comments. Apart from its native p2p capabilities, I would also consider this for interconnecting many peers: [https://www.linux-projects.org/rpi-videoconference-demo-os/](http://Rpi%20Video%20Conference%20DEMO%20OS).

That essentially is a ready-to-use OS image for Raspberry Pi providing a audio/video conference room (thanks to [Janus SFU](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videoroomtest.html)) at boot to which many Raspberry Pi's (including the one running the OS) with camera, microphone, display and speakers attached or PCs, smart phones, and so on can publish/subscribe their/other's audio or video streams. The Raspberry Pi running the OS can eventually decide to connect to any video room on Internet like the above in the above link, not just the "local" one. No browser is required on the Rpi side as UV4L uses all the hardware directly and has native support for WebRTC (it even supports H264 hardware encoding/decoding). Both Janus Gateway and UV4L can be set up with any given list of STUN/TURN servers and have been used successfully with AWS instances too.

There is a built-in web page in UV4L making all the above possible with a few mouse clicks. However, with the **UV4L RESTFul API** (and with the help of the panel for testing this API) you can write/customize your own web application for specific purposes (e.g. create a private, password protected room with a given number of publishers or subscribers matching the requirements in your case)

Comment: Thanks spippulus. As I understand it however if a Pi is running the UV4L conference room behind a NAT then you can call out from there but you cannot call in as the port / IP of the Pi is unknown and being potentially a restricted cone NAT it wont accept a connection unless it initiated the transaction. So my planned solution is a web socket service on each Pi connecting to an AWS server. That server will require the Pi owner to login, map the login to the socket, send a Jitsi URL to the Pi over the socket and send the same URL to the caller.

Comment: Then install Janus on AWS as I said and have UV4L connect to that instance instead. Do not reimplement the wheel. Use WebRTC with TURN/STUN to help the peers for the NAT traversal as that is the standard made to overcome all those difficulties. It would be hard to implement all that stuff via websockets reliably.

Comment: As an update to this; I have struggled to get UV4L working with a USB camera. I have reimaged and reinstalled around 5 times to try various approaches, but always with the same result: the mjpeg stream on UV4L-Server works fine but with the WebRTC options I just get a blank camera feed (but audio is OK). I have had no response from their email form so far either.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the part where you stream through your server, and just use WebRTC.

It's peer-to-peer, works in-browser, has automatic codec negotiation, NAT traversal, everything you need.  All you need to host then is a signalling server and a TURN server for when both peers are firewalled.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I considered that, but isnt WebRTC between two browsers only? I will not be running a client browser session on the Pi, just background processes in Python. Its also my understanding that you need to accept an inbound WebRTC connection through the browser, and I want the connection to be accepted automatically. I am wrong there as well?

Comment: @LeeMelbourne WebRTC works between whatever you want it to work between.  It's commonly used between browsers, yes, but there's no reason that the Pi can't be a peer as well.  And no, you don't need to accept a WebRTC connection.  WebRTC connections also aren't really inbound or outbound... there's an initiator that sends the first signalling information, then the two peers negotiate, and the direction in which they connect could go either way depending on the ICE candidate chosen.

Comment: So it seems its not so easy to setup a WebRTC session without a browser. This post has not had a reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292852/python-wrapper-for-webrtc-client-library and this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569445/webrtc-without-a-browser indicates I would need to somehow use the native WebRTC libraries...which seems to be opening up a coding can of worms. I will keep searching, but I am yet to find a nice simple way to run a Python process that will initiate or wait for a WebRTC connection. This does seem to be a capability very much tied to browsers.

Comment: @LeeMelbourne https://github.com/kclyu/rpi-webrtc-streamer  https://www.linux-projects.org/2017/04/29/uv4l-webrtc-for-pizero/  It's not any more of a can of worms than it has to be.

Comment: It looks like a lot has been added to UV4L. Thanks for the pointer. I looked at that a long time ago and had forgotten about it.

Comment: Actually WebRTC does not provide NAT traversal. This needs to be provided by ICE, STUN or TURN. (A useful discussion is available here https://webrtchacks.com/an-intro-to-webrtcs-natfirewall-problem/) I think a server implementation for these would be more complex than video re-streaming. UV4L is essentially a video driver but it provides many other utilities including a streaming server. However that streaming server would sit on the Pi behind the NAT and therefore still be unreachable. The link to UV4L was valuable however, as it led me to Jitsi - which I think is a viable solution.

Comment: @LeeMelbourne I'm well aware of how WebRTC works.  If you read my answer again, you'll note I mentioned to you how to get this going.  In most cases (~88%), you don't need TURN.  Public STUN servers are pre-configured in browsers, or you can specify your own.  If you run your own TURN server, you get STUN with it.  In any case, like I said, you wouldn't run these servers on the Pi, you would run them elsewhere.  The Pis would be one of the peers.  If you think you're getting out of this requirement with Jitsi, you're wrong.  Jitsi is that server.